# Accidently Hooked an Application using SpyStudio

Tags: windows, hook

Yesterday I was doing some experiments and I tried to take control over an application and clicked Hook on that application. Now I am not able to take that application out of hook.

This application is very important, and I don't know how to Unhook that application.